# RasterIO saves wrong coordinate system when writing to a new file

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I am trying to open, perform a calculation then save to a new tif file using RasterIO without changing the coordinate system.

My input tif is in *GDA 1994 MGA Zone 54* and has a wkt string of

```
 PROJCS["GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_54",GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994",DATUM["GDA_1994",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",141],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

RasterIO, for the same tif,  reads and writes the coordinate system as  *UTM Zone 54, Southern Hemisphere* and which has a wkt string of

```
PROJCS["UTM Zone 54, Southern Hemisphere",GEOGCS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",DATUM["unknown",SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",141],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Both these coordinate system have the same Proj4 string. It seems that RasterIO creates its crs.wkt string from the proj4 string, not from the one provided by the input tif.

Is there a way using RasterIO to read the wkt string from the tif and use it when saving to a new file?

Here's my code so far:

```
smin=0
smax=255
with rasterio.open('input_94mga54.tif') as src:
    band = src.read(1,masked=True)
    rescaled = (band - band.min()) * ( smax - smin) / (band.max() - band.min()) + smin
    with rasterio.open('rescaled_94mga54.tif', 'w', **src.meta) as dst:
        dst.write_band(1, rescaled)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since posting this question, I have found a partial answer.

You can assign a WKT string of the coordinate system using

```
from osgeo import gdal
out_meta['crs'] = gdal.Open('input_94mga54.tif').GetProjectionRef()
```

This saves the correct WKT to the file (confirmed by checking using GDAL methods) however as soon as you read the new file and look at the WKT using `src.crs.wkt` it displays the incorrect WKT of *UTM Zone 54, Southern Hemisphere*.

Not sure what impact has on reprojections.

---

Just another update - This has now been fixed in rasterio v1.1.14 and above.